# Creating a for-loop to iterate through a large array of URL

Tags: php, for-loop

Right now I am in a Coding bootcamp, and for our capstone we have to grab a URL string that is separated by commas. I have no clue on how to start an iteration over them. I have been messing with it for a couple days in between other parts of the project and finally got to a breaking point. We have them all setup within the json file, 3 URL per character separated by a comma. We are trying to iterate through all of it and get them separated into individual pieces.
We used the explode method to get them to separate via the comma,

```
$c = explode(",", $currentValue->gamePictureUrl);
var_dump($c);
```

Now we have to figure out how to iterate over the other ones within the array using a 'for loop'. Any help is appreciated.

This is the first time I have had to deal with something like this, and being as I am just a few weeks into the bootcamp, kind of struggling. Again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the other ones"? You can use `foreach ($c as $url)` to iterate over these URLs.

Comment: Hi Torske, quite frankly I don't understand the question ... Could you provide sample data of what you start with and, where you want to end with it ?